# Getting strange error when updating Reachability

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, reachability

I had reachability 2.0 in my app and I just copy/pasted reachability 2.2 into it.  When I build it, I now get the following errors:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting duplicate symbol errors. This means that you still have reachability classes or objects in your project. Try cleaning and double check that you only have one reachability class in your project.

Comment: I did a clean and double checked.  I only have 1 copy.  Unless there is  copy in one of the libraries?

Comment: That is possible. If you remove class and you project still compiles then this is the case.